RegexRenamer, how to add leading zeros?
I have hundreds of files with names of type "xx S1E1 y1", "xx S2E15 y2", "xx S3E100 y3".
With RegexRenamer I'm trying to add leading zeros after E, but I haven't been able to do so, it always put the leading zeros before E.
(I need E1 to become E001, E10 to E010 and do nothing with E100.)
E.g. for those file names that are "xx S1E[1-9] xx", I'm trying:
Match: (E\d{1})
Replace: 0$0
Which causes S1E1 to become S10E1 instead of S1E01.
Anyone knows how to do this properly with RegexRenamer?

Search about capture groups here.

The reason that you couldn't insert anything in between E and 1 is because you consumed both characters at the same time, there's no way to put anything in the middle of a single match without using a programming language.

Try this regex
(?<=E)((?=\d(?!\d))|\d(?!\d\d))

And replace with
0$0

Not sure if RegexRenamer supports conditional substitution, but here's a workaround. The trick is when there's only one digit after E, it matches twice (zero-width character after E, and the following digit). So it could insert two 0s.
When there are two digits after E, it only matches once (the digit after it), and only one 0 is inserted.
And if there are more than 2 digits, it matches nothing.
See test cases

In order to deal with single-digit episode numbers (e.g. E1), OP could just run the tool twice with the same patterns. The first pass will turn E1 into E01 and the second pass will turn it into E001.

It probably makes sense to to make the pattern a little less general in case there are series/episode names that contain E1 and the like. For instance by using (?<=S\d+E)....

Thank you, this is working fine.
I actually somehow managed to add the leading zeros with multiple steps (some space adding & removing) but your solution works in one go.

@GoodNightNerdPride If OP could run the tool multiple times, (?<=E)\d(?!\d{2}) would be good enough. Also I didn’t add more restrictions, assuming E would be fine according to OP’s attempt. The thing is not all regex engine supports non-fixed width lookbehinds.
